# max and min dates returning different than head, tail of sorted list

Tags: r

I found some puzzling behavior. Given a list of 50 dates:

```
structure(c("15513", "12830", "16503", "-3628", "15833", "13553", 
"473", "17126", "7916", "74", "4736", "7712", "12726", "8684", 
"16217", "14725", "11836", "7061", "4687", "8733", "17176", "17175", 
"16155", "14005", "14635", "-1793", "4296", "15316", "4746", 
"6865", "14228", "5177", "4543", "1936", "10372", "-1393", "13648", 
"17267", "9177", "10380", "9427", "9527", "-1375", "2133", "13966", 
"336", "1925", "9611", "15601", "9218"), class = "Date")
```

I ran this:

```
head(sort(b), 1) ## prints "1960-01-26"
tail(sort(b), 1) ## prints "2017-04-11"

max(b)           ## prints "1996-04-25"
min(b)           ## prints "1966-03-28"
```

But what really confuses me is when all the printed values are in one list, `max` and `min` return the expected result.

```
dc = as.Date(c("1960-01-26", "2017-04-11", "1996-04-25", "1966-03-28"))
max(dc)    ## prints "2017-04-11"
min(dc)    ## prints "1960-01-26"
```

Why is this?

Comment: Must be something in the way `max` and `min` interpret date values, but I don't see anything in the documentation. Another wrinkle... if you use `which.max` and `which.min` it returns the appropriate index values.

Comment: Also if you return `max(as.double(b))`, you get the correct value.

Comment: For reasons beyond me, `min` and `max` are returning the min and max of your vector interpreted as characters. Make `temp <- c("15513",...,"9218")` and `range(temp)` will return `"-1375" "9611"` which correspond to the dates `"1996-04-25" "1966-03-28"`. I have no clue why your data is interpreted sometimes as a Date class and sometimes as a character class.

Comment: That's what I figured, that it was interpreting as character values. Which is strange since I've frequently used `max` and `min` functions on dates and have never run into this problem before (unless the values were accidentally stored `as.character` in which case converting them to `Dates` imminently solved the problem).

Comment: This does not look like a valid "Date" object. How is it constructed? It should have a `storage.mode` of "double" instead of "character" -- e.g. be something like `as.Date(as.numeric(unclass(b)), origin = "1970-01-01")`. `min` and `max` dispatch (through `Summary`) correctly but instead of numeric vectors they receive character. On the other hand, `sort` operates correctly since it relies on `xtfrm` when facing objects with a class attribute and, in this case, `xtfrm.Date` coerces to numeric before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

The min() and max() functions are only for input of class "numerical"
The vector in your example i class "Date".
For:

```
structure(min(as.numeric(example)), class ="Date")
```

where "example" is your vector you get the right solution...

Hope this makes it clear.

Cheers

Comment: Not just numeric, also character class objects accepted. See `?max` for details.

Comment: ^ agreed. If you return `max(as.character(b))` you still get `2017-04-11` implying that `max` can order character values.